# Constraints When Using NMinimize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to put in constraints like `z.x1 >=1, z.x2 >= 1` where `z, x1, x2` are vectors, but I do not want to list them out. Instead, I want to write something like `x.z >= 1` where `x = {x1, x2,...}`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved: Use `Thread[x.z >= 1]`.